# React app fails to run with Apache reverse proxy

Tags: reactjs, linux, apache, reverse-proxy, serve

I'm using the `reverse-proxy` apache2 module to forward any request from `https://my_server.com/test_app/` to the react production app, which is running on `:3000`.

If i'm using `https://my_server.com:3000`, everything works fine. But `https://my_server.com/test_app/` fails then to get the static files and react fails to load.
It seems to request the static files on the port 80, but my react app is running on 3000.

How can i fix this?

**package.json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  ...
}
```

**httpd.conf**

```
ProxyPass /test_app http://localhost:3000
```

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `serve`, i just placed the contents of the build into a directory in `/var/www/html/<Some-Directory>` (So i'm using Apache only). I had to define `basename` for the `<Router />` and update my links, but seems to work fine for now.